# Difficulty Customizing Jira Templates: Seeking Solutions

Tags: templates, jira, workflow, customization, agile

I'm struggling to customize Jira templates to fit my team's specific needs, despite following the provided guidelines.

I expected the customization process to be straightforward and intuitive, allowing me to tailor the templates efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

What your challenge?. Your post sounds more like a generic statement, rather than a specific problem than can be answered.